# Stub? Just a place-holder/marker waiting for further development?

Tags: english-to-german, technical-terminology

Stub as in [Wikipedia's usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Stub) is where they shotgun-create loads of minimal skeleton pages that will hopefully be filled in with details later. I don't like *Stummel* so well. *Kontrollabschnitt* is close perhaps. Wikipedia.de uses *Lückenhaft* which sounds kludge, IMHO. Ideas?

Comment: I disagree with the description of stubs, but this may be due to different emphasis between German and English WP versions. *Lückenhaft* in German WP only indicates **some** known gaps, the article may be quite complete in other respects. This is, however, far from the *minimal skeleton* used in top-down programming, so more details would be welcome.

Answer (score 8):

*Rumpfartikel* oder *Artikelrumpf* would be usable here.

Composites with "Rumpf-" are being used as "minimum" in places in German (like "Rumpfmannschaft", for example.

"Stummel" or "Kontrollabschnitt" wouldn't fit at all,unfortunately.

"Platzhalter" would be another possibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, "Rumpf" can also be interpreted as "the central part", and thereby e.g. the body of a document (i.e. the core part of the document, without the headline and the initial summary etc.). This would be the opposite of what "stub" intends to express.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Apparently, you haven't read Wikipedia's definition of a stub: *A stub is an article that, although providing some useful information, lacks the breadth of coverage expected from an encyclopedia, and that is capable of expansion.* - That is, it also fulfills the definition of "central part".

Comment: I was referring to the "central part" in a technical sense - as I wrote, the "body" of a document. That is, the complete text without any lack in breadth of coverage, but without "metadata" such as a title and a summary. Imagine a book from which you cut away everything before the first page of the first chapter and everything after the last page of the last chapter. That is not a "stub", but I might call it "Rumpf" in German.

Comment: Den Vorschlag "Rumpfartikel" finde ich gut. Vgl. http://www.b5wiki.de/wiki/Kategorie:Rumpfartikel . O.R.Mapper hat zwar Recht, dass "Rumpf" eine gewisse Ambivalenz hat, aber als Vorsilbe deutet es ganz klar auf eine Unvollständigkeit hin. Vgl. z.B. [Rumpfgesetz](https://www.handelsblatt.com/politik/deutschland/gesundheitspolitik-revolte-gegen-spahns-reform-der-krankenkassen-aok-oeffnung-vor-dem-aus/24505298.html?ticket=ST-12220648-t09CpZN0fv5jPLOAeyVz-ap5).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what other people call it, but I refer to stubs that contain a skeleton structure and predefined text blocks (*Textbausteine*) as **Textgerüst** or simply [**Gerüst**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ger%C3%BCst).

Answer (score 1):

*Rudiment* or *rudimentär* seem fitting, this is used in software development in a comparable sense: "Feature xy wurde bisher nur rudimentär umgesetzt, eine bessere Implementation folgt in Version z."

Maybe *Bruchstück* or *bruchstückhaft*, which is often used for something incomplete, although in a literal sense, "Bruchstück" suggests a part of something that was whole before. which isn't a good fit.

*Ansatz* comes to mind, too. *Anfang* would be an even more optimistic take: "Dieser Artikel ist nur ein Ansatz/Anfang."

*Lückenhaft* does seem usable to me, but that would be more fitting for an article that has weaknesses and missing pieces in some aspects, not so much a very short one.

"Stummel" and "Kontrollabschnitt" don't work at all, as @tofro already stated.

"Rumpf" works, but what I don't find perfect about it is that "Rumpf" (hull, trunk, torso), like "lückenhaft", suggests that the main part is already done and only some additional aspects are needed.

Comment: A Kontrollabschnitt, like a ticket stub, indicates that a ticket was bought, correct?

Comment: @147pm: Yes, that's the part of the classic ticket that is teared off on "Kontrolle", the striped part in this picture: https://maru-versand.de/Eintrittskarten_mit_Eckabriss_blau

Comment: Please comment when you downvote.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell which meaning of "stub" was meant when someone decided to use it for a minimal article, but my best guess it's taken from programming (especially top-down) where stub is a non-functioning function/subroutine/class that consists of a declaration with no actual code. Basically, in order to write the upper level code before taking care of the lower level code, you have to "stub-in" these empty declarations to keep the compiler happy so you can get something you can execute and test. If so, then apparently the German term for this is simply *stub*; see [de.Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stub_(Programmierung).) But I don't think "stub" is a particularly good match for the Wikipedia meaning, I imagine that someone decided a bit of jargon was needed and the word fit no worse than other possible choices. So given that jargon words are somewhat arbitrary, I don't see that *Lückenhaft* as a bad choice. In any case, once jargon becomes widely used by the community it's pretty much set in stone; the effort and disruption involved in changing it would far outweigh any possible benefit.

Answer (score 0):

For Wikipedia articles, the anglicism *Stub* fits best. But it could be translated as:

> Kurzartikel

In general, you could call a *place-holder/marker waiting for further development* metaphorically ***Baustelle***:

> Der Text ist noch eine Baustelle.

Or you could say:

> Der Artikel ist unfertig.

Both convey the very concept that the current state of the work needs to be amended while the main sections might already be finished.

*Skelett* is also possible, but sounds quite technical/anatomical. The metaphor is similar to *Baustelle*.

> Der Text ist (noch) ein Skelett (*or:* Textskelett).

Answer (score -1):

You are asking us to come up with a word that doesn't exist in German.

Languages often use different linguistic constructs to express the same concept. In this case, what corresponds to the English word *stub* is best expressed using an adjective-noun phrase such as "unvollständiger Artikel".

The propositions in the other answers are neologisms and won't be understood out of context. I don't know what a "Textgerüst" or an "Artikelrumpf" are.

---

Personally I think that Wikipedians should decide what they want to call the differents functions of Wikipedia. People there are just as knowledgeable about German as we are. Why don't you open a discussion there?

Comment: Note a *composite* and a *neologism* are two different things.